# Oracle mview logs in use?

Tags: oracle

How do I check if a mview log is in use?

```
select * from sys.mlog$
```

I have 2 rows in the above sys table but where is the connections to mviews?

**Edit**: It is very possible my question is unclear due to lack of understanding. I'll try to rephrase here:

I see 2 mview logs in my database. I also see the tables that they belongs too. My understanding is that mview logs are used for "REFRESH FAST" mviews. Maybe they can be used for other stuff too. So before I deletes these mview logs i want to know if they are in use. Can i somehow query mviews that depends on these mview logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query.

```
select  master, log, temp_log from sys.mlog$ where mowner = user and master = 'Table Name';
```

Master denotes the table name. Mview log file can exists without materialized view.

You can use `GET_MV_DEPENDENCIES` procedure of `DBMS_MVIEW` package to know the MViews related to a particular table.

Example: `dbms_mview.get_mv_dependencies (owner.table, output);`

**Update**
Above procedure will give you the MViews related to a table. Query `USER/ALL_MVIEWS` to know its refresh method.

```
SQL> select mview_name, refresh_method from user_mviews;

MVIEW_NAME                     REFRESH_
------------------------------ --------
M_VIEW_A                       FAST
```

If it's refresh method is `FAST` then you need the MView logs.

**Documentation:**[Refresh Dependent Materialized Views with REFRESH_DEPENDENT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/refresh.htm)

Comment: Maybe I am blind, but doesn't "master" points to the table and "log" points to the mview log? "temp_log" is null on my 2 rows. So i still need to known if any mviews needs these mview logs.

Comment: Great, are we sure that mivew logs can only be used by FAST REFRESH mviews?